# Universal Windows Platform - UI not updating when returning from different page

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm learning Universal Windows Platform and I'm currently analysing music player using SoundCloud API from [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/windowsapp/1224/universal-windows-platform-app-uwp-windows-phone-raspberry-pi-2) site. Link to the github project is at the very bottom of the page. To get this project to work variable SoundCloudClientId from App.xaml.cs should be filled in (I used client id from previous example on the same page, not sure if I can paste that).

When application starts the NowPlaying page is loaded and changing tracks causes UI to update accordingly. The problem is when I navigate to any other page and return back to NowPlaying. I can still change music using buttons, but UI doesn't change (song title, album title etc.).

Important parts of the code:
NowPlaying.xaml

```
<ImageBrush x:Name="albumrtImage" ImageSource="Assets\Albumart.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
<TextBlock x:Name="txtSongTitle" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"   Text="Song Title " FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"  />
<TextBlock x:Name="txtAlbumTitle"  Grid.Row="0" Text="Label " HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="20"  Foreground="#9799a5" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

NowPlaying.xaml.cs

```
    async void BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromBackground(object sender, MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        TrackChangedMessage trackChangedMessage;
        if (MessageService.TryParseMessage(e.Data, out trackChangedMessage))
        {
            // When foreground app is active change track based on background message
            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var songIndex = GetSongIndexById(trackChangedMessage.TrackId);
                if (songIndex >= 0)
                {
                    var song = App.likes[songIndex];
                    LoadTrack(song); //Update UI
                }
            });
            return;
        }

        BackgroundAudioTaskStartedMessage backgroundAudioTaskStartedMessage;
        if (MessageService.TryParseMessage(e.Data, out backgroundAudioTaskStartedMessage))
        {
            backgroundAudioTaskStarted.Set();
            return;
        }
    }
    private async void LoadTrack(SoundCloudTrack currentTrack)
    {
        try
        {
            //Change album art
            string albumartImage = Convert.ToString(currentTrack.artwork_url);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(albumartImage))
            {
                albumartImage = @"ms-appx:///Assets/Albumart.png";

            }
            else
            {
                albumartImage = albumartImage.Replace("-large", "-t500x500");
            }
            //Next 3 lines when pages were switched don't cause UI to update
            albumrtImage.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(albumartImage));
            txtSongTitle.Text = currentTrack.title;
            txtAlbumTitle.Text = Convert.ToString(currentTrack.user.username);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog showMessgae = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong. Please try again. Error Details : " + ex.Message);
            await showMessgae.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

After navigating from NowPlaying->Me->NowPlaying and clicking next the track changes, but UI doesn't update as seen on the screen below:

[UI problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHFvP.jpg)

I'm trying to reproduce the problem on a simple example, but without any luck. What could cause this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call this from? Do you see any errors in debug output? Please post a more complete example, or try to find the minimum required code to reproduce this problem.

Comment: There are no errors in debug output. Source code is on the website I linked above, [link to github](https://github.com/dotnetcurry/Windows10-UWP). I'll try to reproduce the issue and post the link below.

Comment: Please don't add the solution to the question or "solved" to the title. Post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. The problem was with cache. The NowPlaying page required putting following property: 
NavigationCacheMode="Required"

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that you can also check navigation mode in OnNavigatedTo method. It can be helpful when for instance you would like to refresh the data when returning to the selected page.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        {
            //refresh the data here...
        }
    }
```